# How to default check true any one radio button using RPGLE program in AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

How to check true any one radio button using RPGLE program in AS400

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6N6m.png)

```
0001.90      A                                 13  3'Warehouse . . . . . .'  
0002.00      A            WAREHOUSE      2Y 0B 14  9SNGCHCFLD                
0002.10      A                                      CHOICE(1 '>W1')          
0002.20      A                                      CHOICE(2 '>W2')
```

this is my DSPF source code, how to check true any one radio button W1 or W2. How to do it?

Expected output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ4fS.png)
How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to introduce the `CHCCTL` keyword, and a variable definition for each choice. See [CHCCTL (Choice Control) keyword for display files](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=80-chcctl-choice-control-keyword-display-files) on the IBM website for details and examples.

You might greatly benefit from finding and working through the [Application Display Programming](https://www.ibm.com/resources/publications/OutputPubsDetails?PubID=SC41571501) PDF, where such techniques are presented.